# How to display total number of running containers in docker?

Tags: docker

`docker ps`

Displays all the running containers
I want to display the total number of running containers
The command,

`docker ps | wc -l`

displays the line count but also counts headers as lines.

How do I exclude headers?
Also, is there another way to print the total number of running containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker info` display the number of running containers like next:

> ```
> Server:
> Containers: 116
>  Running: 3
>  Paused: 0
>  Stopped: 113
> ```

You could format the output using next to get the running containers:

```
$ docker info --format '{{json .ContainersRunning}}'
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting

If you dont use the table directive it wont show the headers

You should be able to pipe that in to wc -l